# Webpart display in all web application

Tags: web-application

I have created webpart and deploy it on web application level. It is displaying in all web application. How can i restrict to display on specific site.

Regards,

Comment: It's depends on scope of feature or where you deployed your webpart solution to, if you used central admin to deploy your solution to all of web applications then it will be displayed to all of web applications http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/understanding-sharepoint-feature-scopes

Answer (score 0):

Scope the webpart feature to site or web, make sure Activate on Default is not set on the feature properties. Deploy your solution and the activate the feature from site collection feature (if site scoped) or site features (if web scoped) from the site settings

Comment: with this its not activate by default but it is visible in all web application. How to restrict that?

Comment: You can't scope it more. But you can make the Feature hidden, and activate it with powershell